# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil' for some values only

Tags: mysql, ios, json, crash

I'm trying to get informations from MySQL data base, I did this :

```
 NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/php_files/additif.php?keyword=Gélatine"];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
 NSDictionary *serverResponseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

but application crashes with message : `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'`
The problem is that when I change the value of `keyword` to E120 or another string in the `strURL`,everything is fine and application runs without any problems. I checked the database and it contains a row with Gélatine informations and I checked also the `strURL` and it's correct. 
Any suggestions please ?

Comment: try to encode the url

Comment: I tried : `NSString* encodedUrl = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                            NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
now app doesn't crash but it doesn't display results from json when `keyword`contains : é character like Gélatine case.